# C# passing Object from List<T> as parameter

Tags: c#

I have a List where i store some values. I defined an event which should pop up and return the last Object from that List to its EventArgs-Class-Constructor.

But when the Event gets fired, i get a `System.NullException` at this line:

`OnID(this, new OnIDEventArgs(ID_List.Last()));`

**Im trying to pass the last IDs-Object to the OnIDEventArgs-Constructor. Why is this a NullException?**

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, OnIDEventArgs e);
public event EventHandler OnID;

IDs result = ID_List.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TID == tid_value);


    if (result != null)
       { //stuff }
    else {
       ID_List.Add(new IDs
                    {
                        TID = tid_value,
                        CENTID = centid_value,
                        IDCount = 1
                    });
       OnID(this, new OnIDEventArgs(ID_List.Last())); //System.NullException comes up here
    }
```

IDs class

```
public class IDs
{
    public string TID { get; internal set; }
    public string CENTID { get; internal set; }
    public int IDCount { get; internal set; }
}
```

EventArgs Class

```
public class OnIDEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string LastTID { get; private set; }
        public string LastCENTID { get; private set; }
        public int IDCount { get; private set; }
        public OnIDEventArgs(IDs result)
        {
            this.LastTID = result.TID;
            this.LastCENTID = result.CENTID;
            this.IDCount = result.IDCount;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to that nothing subscribed to the `OnID` event, so the `OnID` delegate is null and thus calling `Invoke` on it will throw an NRE.

To avoid this, simply check whether `OnID` is null first:

```
if (OnID != null) {
    OnID(this, new OnIDEventArgs(ID_List.Last()))
}
```

Or:

```
OnID?.Invoke(this, new OnIDEventArgs(ID_List.Last())
```

Comment: The last one is safe. With the first one, in theory, to avoid reading the underlying field of the event twice, which could be problematic if another thread unsubscribed the last subscriber in the meantime, you ought to do `var onIDDel = OnID; if (onIDDel != null) {
    onIDDel(this, new OnIDEventArgs(ID_List.Last()));
}`.